# Database design and ActiveRecord querying, with polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I'm trying to design a database structure where Users have various types of 'relationships' with People.

These People have Activities associated with them.

I'm trying to retrieve these Activites based on people with a certain relationship to the given User.

The following line is far from correct but I think it gives the gist of what I'm trying to get at.

```
User.find(1).customers.join(:person).activities
```

Also important is that my query returns the other attributes on the Relationship table

I'm wanting to return something like (in json):

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  name: 'Carl',
  activities: {
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Swimming',
      relationship: 'Customer',
      person: {
        id: 1
        name: 'Sam',
      },
      {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customers
  has_many :friends
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord

end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :person
  # additional attributes on this model we need
end

class Customer < Relationship
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :activities
end

class Friend < Relationship
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :activities
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  # Has polymorphic association 'owner'
  # owner_type (i.e. 'Customer')
  # owner_id
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Any guidance on how to get at these relationships, preserving the data in the specified join table?
Thank you!